# .htaccess redirect subdomain to ssl site

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, ssl

I want to let my site http://subdomain.domain.com redirect to another external SSL-encrypted domain https://subdomain.external.com, while keeping the original address in the browsing bar. As far as I know, it is possible with CNAME to do this very easily, but the problem is that it redirects to the external link without SSL encryption.

I have been told that this can be done with .htaccess file, which right now has the following contents:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Can you help me know how should I modify the .htaccess file to meet my requirement? Thank you very much!

Juan

Comment: You won't be able to have a redirection while keeping the original address in the location bar.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it with PHP:

```
$redirect = "https://www.ssl.com".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
header("Location: $redirect");
exit;
```

Then you have to route all requests to this PHP file via .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ index.php [QSA]
```

Comment: Hi Richard, thank you for your answer. Where should I include that PHP snippet? Take into account that my purpose is to keep in the browser bar the original address, while having the redirection to the second address, and SSL-encrypted (the SSL certificate belongs to the second address, not to the original).

Comment: @juanba1984: Does I understand it right? You have site A (non-SSL) and site B (SSL). And you want to display content of site B on site A without redirecting? What is the sense? Then SSL is useless, if you do not use an iFrame or some shit like this ;-)

Comment: That's it. Just because of Branding matters, I want to keep in my browsing bar my domain, while displaying contents from other website, but SSL-encrypted. Right now, as it is implemented, I have two options:

 1). Display content from the second website, without SSL-encryption, keeping my domain in the browsing bar.
 2). Visit the second website, displaying in the browsing bar the address of the second website (not my Brand), SSL-encrypted.

I will try the options you have mentioned and let you know. Thank you very much!

Comment: @juanba1984: You can get the other website's content via file_get_contents - but then it is not SSL-encrypted between you and your visitors.